# How can I change the background image of each page in the JQuery booklet plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**How can I change the background image of each page in the JQuery booklet plugin?**Theoretically I think I understand it, but practically I must be doing something wrong in the syntax. I am still really new to JavaScript in general. I am assigning each of the (page) div's it's own id, I think I am getting that part right, and then I want to assign each of them a background image in the C.S.S.. But I am not sure how I should do this. does the statement start with a "." or "#", and should it go in or out of .b-loads {parameters?}

In my CSS:

```
     .booklet .b-load  {
         text-align:center;
     } 
     .cover {
         background-image url(images\00c.png)
     }
     #genesis01n0001 {
         background-image url(images\00c.png)
     }
```

In the HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id="mybook">
     <div class="b-load">
     <div id="cover">
     <h1>The Old Testament!</h1>
     </div>
     <div id="genesis01n0001"> 
     <h3>In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.</h3>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#cover {
    background-image:url(images/00c.png);
}
#genesis01n0001 {
    background-image:url(images/00c.png);
}
```

You forgot the ":" and the ";" om your css! And why don't you use "/" instead of "\"?
Another note: In your css, "#" describes an id and "." describes a class.

Comment: RSPLAK .b!tch slapped the ignorance out of my syntax, and [Paul Wilkins](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/javascript-15/how-can-i-change-background-image-each-page-jquery-booklet-plugin-744357.html#post4839311) told me where to stick it. But I couldn't see what I was missing until I used [Chris Pederick,s](http://http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) developer bar to see the div structure being generated by Will's booklet. The left and right page wrappers were hiding my custom backgrounds.